# Bootstrap date-time picker asp.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, date-format, datetimepicker

I am using this function

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({});
        });
    </script>
```

And this code to show the datetime:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeNameDateTimeFormat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm datetimepicker"} })
```

However, css is not working at all, it renders calendar on the side of the page as a items one after another.

How and where should I include css?

At the end i want to have output like "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
p.s.
HH:mm can be DateTime.Now.

Comment: What datetimepicker is this?

Comment: It is bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Then you should edit you answer to make that clear (there are multiple datetimepickers - but the script you have included suggests its the [xdsoft datetime picker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/))

Comment: I ended up using datetimepicker that u suggested and this tutorial was really helpfull. I had to add jquery.simplemodal.js since I am using this in modal view (_Create) and now i have problem with buttons I have for Add/Cancel (The modal is not closing wheather i clock on Add or Cancel). Have you met this problem before? Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I fixed it, problem was I was using jquery.js in Layout and in Create. Works like charm. Thanks and post as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using xdsoft datetimepicker as @StephenMuecke suggested. This is an excelent tutorial for that purpose with everything that xdsoft datetimepickler offers:

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I had difficulties because I included the jquery scripts in my Layout and my _Create PartialView, so if you are using Partial view, be careful.

Answer (score 1):

You can change datetime format as per your need:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })
```

Comment: Tried that, and works perfectly, but I need output with time too -> dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm.

Comment: You should use dateTime picker. format for jquery datepicker is different than c# format. e.g mm = '02' & MM = 'february'.
find datetimepicker at http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: @Ajay, in the end i ended up using xdsoft-datetimepicker, but StephenMuecke first suggested it. So if he posts it as an answer I will accept his, if he does not, you can post your suggestion as an answer and I will accept yours. Anyway, thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Use textboxFor instead of editorFor.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeNameDateTimeFormat,"{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm datetimepicker"} })<br>
```

Also include the css on the layout if you are using it on multiple pages/ on the page where it is used.
normal style tag (`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">` ) should do.
Go through this tutorial [Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-1)